# Tomcat7 logrotate: superx_default_xml.log.gz already exists

Tags: tomcat, cron, tomcat7, logrotate

Every day I get a mail with the following error message from my cron:

```
/etc/cron.daily/tomcat7:
gzip: /var/log/tomcat7/superx_default_xml.log.gz already exists;    not overwritten
gzip: /var/log/tomcat7/superx.log.gz already exists;    not overwritten
gzip: /var/log/tomcat7/superx-dbforms.log.gz already exists;    not overwritten
gzip: /var/log/tomcat7/saiku.log.gz already exists; not overwritten
gzip: /var/log/tomcat7/superx_default.log.gz already exists;    not overwritten
```

I´ve installed Tomcat7 on a Ubuntu 14.04 and I´ven´t set anything at the logrotate confs. I tried to set the following, but the error persists:

```
/var/log/tomcat7/superx.log {
  copytruncate
  weekly
  rotate 52
  compress
  nomail
  missingok
  create 640 tomcat7 adm
}
/var/log/tomcat7/superx-dbforms.log {
  copytruncate
  weekly
  rotate 52
  compress
  nomail
  missingok
  create 640 tomcat7 adm
}
/var/log/tomcat7/saiku.log {
  copytruncate
  weekly
  rotate 52
  compress
  nomail
  missingok
  create 640 tomcat7 adm
}
```