# Tomcat8 on Ubuntu .log.gz already exists not overwritten

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat8, ubuntu-16.04, logrotate

On our Tomcat servers I regularly see warnings like below:

```
/etc/cron.daily/tomcat8:
gzip: /var/log/tomcat8/app1/app1.log.gz already exists; not overwritten
gzip: /var/log/tomcat8/app2/app2.log.gz already exists; not overwritten
gzip: /var/log/tomcat8/app3/app3.log.gz already exists; not overwritten
gzip: /var/log/tomcat8/app4/app4.log.gz already exists; not overwritten
```

I found a similar issue as discussed in [Tomcat7 logrotate: superx_default_xml.log.gz already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474337/tomcat7-logrotate-superx-default-xml-log-gz-already-exists/39764771#39764771) however an answer was never provided.

Although search for an answer I can't seem to find a solution for this problem and was hoping if someone here could point me in the right directlion.

We are running our Tomcat 8 servers on Tomcat8 servers on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`-        find /var/log/$NAME/ -name \*.$LOGEXT -daystart -mtime +0 -print0 \
 +        find /var/log/$NAME/ -name \*[0-9].$LOGEXT -daystart -mtime +0 -print0 \`

log4j adds date suffix to log files names on rotation, so there must be a digit there so just add this digit to glob in `/etc/cron.daily/tomcat8`

Answer (score 0):

My 2cents solution:

Add the following line in /etc/default/tomcat8

```
LOGEXT="20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].log log.20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] txt"
```

This will select, for compression and purging, files like

```
/var/log/tomcat8/localhost.2019-09-09.log
/var/log/tomcat8/app1/app1.log.2019-09-09
/var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.2019-09-09.txt
```

and leave alone `app1.log` files, which presumably will be renamed by a log4j appender.

Thus `/etc/cron.daily/tomcat8` does not need to be changed.

Works with the tomcat8 of the Debian 9 (stretch) distribution. YMMV.